# Azure Search - querying for ampersand character

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm trying to find all records which contain `&` symbol, which is reserved. I'm using `search`, not `$filter`.

According to documentation, it can not be escaped with `\%`, and should be escaped as HTML url part to `%26`.

Trying SDK and Search explorer to find any options on how to search, but with no succeed:

1. `&`
2. `*&*`
3. `*%26*`
4. `%26`
5. `\%26`

**UPD**

Document example:

```
{
    "test": "Hello & World"
```

Search query: `search=%26&searchFields=test&$select=test`

**UPD 2**

```
public class MyType
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [IsFilterable]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsSortable]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

class Program
    {
        private static SearchServiceClient CreateSearchServiceClient()
        {
            string searchServiceName = "XXXXXX";
            string adminApiKey = "XXXXXXX";

            var serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(adminApiKey));
            return serviceClient;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = CreateSearchServiceClient();
            var def = new Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index
            {
                Name = "temp-test-reserved1",
                Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<MyType>()
            };
            client.Indexes.Create(def);
            var c = client.Indexes.GetClient("temp-test-reserved1");

            var actions = new IndexAction<MyType>[]
            {
                IndexAction.Upload(new MyType{ Id = "1", Test = "Hello & World" }),
                IndexAction.Upload(new MyType{ Id = "2", Test = "& test start" }),
                IndexAction.Upload(new MyType{ Id = "3", Test = "test end &" })
            };
            c.Documents.Index(IndexBatch.New(actions));
        }
    }
```

`search=%26&searchFields=Test&$select=Test`

Comment: Did you try all those options in both SDK and Search explorer?
I am posting an answer below, but for the SDK option 1 should've just worked, unless you change the defaults. Can you post a code example in case that didn't work

Comment: Also, just to make sure - it should be escaped to `%26` (as stated in your list) and not `%24` (as stated in the sentence above it)

Comment: I want to fix it least with Search Explorer. Updating the post

Comment: Are there any other reasons why the document might be filtered out?
Could you try using the keyword analyzer (instead of the default analyzer) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#AnalyzerTable and see if that helps?

Comment: this approach did not help. actually, I don't think it's ok to have entire field as a token in our case. we need a full text scored search on this field. also, we are using search and filter capabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely can't find `&` because it's being removed at indexing and query time, since it's considered to be punctuation by the default analyzer. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-analyzers) has more details on lexical analysis in Azure Cognitive Search. If you need to preserve ampersands while still tokenizing text on whitespace boundaries, you'll need to create a [custom analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers).

Answer (score 1):

In the search explorer field on the Azure portal try the query `&search=%26`(as shown below)

[image]

In the SDK, only if you have set the [`UseHttpGetForQueries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.searchindexclient.usehttpgetforqueries?view=azure-dotnet) parameter to `true`, you would need to think of URL encoding the '&' character. By default, this parameter is set to `false` in which case you don't need to encode it.

More documentation about escaping/encoding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#encoding-unsafe-and-reserved-characters-in-urls)

Comment: an example with Search Explorer does not work. It returns nothing